# Why does merging faces with 'F' cause loopcuts to be messed up?

Tags: edit-mode, faces

I tried recalculating normals on the in and outside which did not help.

If you look closely the angled face on the tip was made the same way with connecting vertices to become faces with <kbd>F</kbd>.

[image: Same here]

The loop cut does not go over the newly merged faces

[image: The loop cut does not go over the newly merged faces]

[image: Same here]

Comment: if you mean that you can't loopcut it's because the edge loop meets a ngon